# Display 3 numerical values ​in java with greater, less and equal

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, case, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to show 3 different values in this code, the highest number, the lowest number and if all the numbers are the same the output should show that they are equal, So far I have only been able to show greater or equal values, but I don't know how to implement the display of the smaller value, does this structure help me to achieve it or should I use another type of structure?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class values

{
    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
        int x, y, z;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("First Value:");

        x = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Second Value:");

        y = s.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Third Value:");

        z = s.nextInt();

        if (x == y && x == z)
    {
        System.out.println("All numbers are equal");
        
    }
        else if(y > z && y > x)

        {
            System.out.println("The highest value is: "+y);

        }
        else if(x > y && x > z)

        {
            System.out.println("The highest value is: "+x);
        }
        else

        {
            System.out.println("The highest value is: "+z);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    if (x == y && x == z) {
        System.out.println("All numbers are equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The highest value is: "+ IntStream.of(x, y, z).max().getAsInt());
        System.out.println("The lowest value is: "+ IntStream.of(x, y, z).min().getAsInt());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this for min and max.

```
int x = 10; int y = 20; int z = 30;
int min = Math.min(Math.min(x,y),z);
int max = Math.max(Math.max(x,y),z);

System.out.println("max = " + max);
System.out.println("min = " + min);
```

Prints

```
max = 30
min = 10
```

If you don't want to use the Math class methods, write your own and use them the same way. These use the `ternary operator ?:` which says that for `expr ? a : b` if the expression is true, return `a`, otherwise return `b`;

```
public static int max (int x, int y) {
   return x > y ? x : y;
}

public static int min (int x, int  y) {
   return x < y ? x : y;
}
```

Finally, you could write methods to take an arbitrary number of arguments and return the appropriate one. These first check for a null array then check for an empty array.

```
public static int min(int ...v) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(v);
   if (v.length == 0) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("No values supplied");
   }
   int min = v[0];
   for(int i = 1; i < v.length; i++) {
       min =  min < v[i] ? min : v[i];
   }
   return min;
}


public static int max(int ...v) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(v);
    if (v.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No values supplied");
    }
    int max = v[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < v.length; i++) {
        max =  max > v[i] ? max : v[i];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be cumbersome to write all the conditions involving all three variables. I would proceed as follows:

1. Initialize separate variables to store the highest, and the lowest value separately. e.g. `int highest = x; int lowest = x;`
2. Compare the current highest and the current lowest with `y` and `z` respectively, change if necessary. e.g. `highest = y > highest : y ? highest; lowest = y < lowest ? y : lowest;`
3. After all comparisons are done, if the highest value is the same as the lowest, then all `x`, `y` and `z` are the same.